# Fill a cell of 4 spanned rows with dots. XSL-FO question

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Using apache fop 1.1.
i'm trying to get something similar to the column of the pic.(dots part, header is ok).

When i have text in variable whSrvDet, i would like to fill the column with the text and  remaining spaces with dots , the four rows.
If variable whSrvDet is empty, all spaces dotted.

Using this xsl-fo code, i get just one line dotted. fo:leader have the same result for me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXdiU.png

```
 `<fo:table-row >
    <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="4"   number-columns-spanned="2" wrap-option="wrap" keep-together="auto" border-right="solid" border-bottom="solid">     
            <fo:block text-align="left" border-bottom-style="dotted" >  
                    <xsl:value-of select="whSrvDet"/>
            </fo:block>

    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row >
`
```

Could you help me?, thank you!

Comment: Which XSL Formatter are you using to generate your PDF?

Comment: sorry, i forgot writting that information: apache fop 1.1

Comment: Background image in table cell with four dots tiled horizontally. Then put white background color on the text to hide them where text is

Comment: Maybe even just one dot with appropriate spacing

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers @KevinBrown. Finally i made 5 substrings of whole text and avoided rowspan. At this way is easier to get better results. Thank you